# Changing the line height in section titles using \titleformat

Tags: sectioning, formatting, baseline

I am using `\titleformat` from the `titlesec` package to restyle sectioning with a rule underneath, but I can't get it to obey the line-height (second) parameter of `\fontsize` (I am assuming that somewhere it is failing to issue a `\par`, so the specified line-height is not being acted on).

In this example, I want the title set solid (14pt type on a 14pt baseline):

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,parskip,multicol,titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
  {\vspace{-\baselineskip}\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont\sffamily\raggedright}
  {\relax}{0pt}
  {\vspace{2mm}}
  [\titlerule]
\setlength{\columnsep}{10mm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\section{This is a demo}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \subsection{Increasing the uptake of STEM candidates}
  \lipsum[1]
  \lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I want the lines in the subsection title to be unleaded. Is there some way to coerce `\titleformat` into doing this?

[image]

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with *unleaded lines*.

Comment: @Bernard It means not spaced. That is, without lead between the lines of metal type so you put one row of letters right below the row above when setting them in place. (I think that's why - I know that's what it means.)

Comment: My apologies for using an old printer's term. Yes, it means without extra space between lines. Also called "set solid".

Comment: @PeterFlynn If you'd said 'set solid' I'd have had no idea at all, unless you planned to turn the printed result into papier mâché.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image: unleaded title ...]

Don't add 2mm of space if you don't want it. At any rate, you certainly don't want to add it in the way you are doing in the place you are doing it ;).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,parskip,multicol,titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
  {\vspace{-\baselineskip}\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont\sffamily\raggedright}
  {\thesubsubsection}{0pt}
  {}
  [\titlerule]
\setlength{\columnsep}{10mm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\section{This is a demo}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \subsection{Increasing the uptake of STEM candidates}
  \lipsum[1]
  \lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

`fix-cm` is no longer required, as I understand it, with any recent installation.

Comment: Thanks...I had clearly misunderstood that parameter: I thought it was for increasing the space below the content.

Comment: @PeterFlynn I think you are doing well to use `titlesec` at all. I can never remember what the parameters do and, when I can, they never seem to do it!

Comment: @PeterFlynn Is this what you wanted, by the way? There was some dispute about this!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,parskip,multicol,titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
  {\vspace{-\baselineskip}\sffamily\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont\filright}
  {\relax}{0pt}
  {\vspace{-3pt}}
  [\vspace{-3pt}\titlerule]
\setlength{\columnsep}{10mm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\section{This is a demo}
\begin{multicols}{2}{\par
  \subsection{Increasing the uptake of STEM candidates}}
  \lipsum[1]
  \lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]